# How to check non-repeating and non-sequential numbers in Laravel or PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

In my, Laravel App has a pin field. Now I want to required for the user so that they give non-repeating, non-sequential numbers in Pin field.
Like: 0598, 9587 Not: 1122, 1298, 4568.

Comment: Could you provide more informatión about your non-repeating and non-sequential policies? because for non-sequential numbers most people will assume consecutive numbers or simpler serial numbers, but -as along as I can see- in your  "not" list those are non-repeating and also non-secuential.

Answer (score 1):

```
function validatePin ($pin) {
    $parts = str_split($pin);

    $previousPart = null;

    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (!$previousPart) {
            $previousPart = $part;
            continue;
        }

        if ($part == $previousPart) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($part == $previousPart + 1) {
            return false;
        }

        $previousPart = $part;
    }

    return true;
}
```